# Every divisor can be written as the difference of two hyperplane sections.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a curve over a number field $k$. We have a homomorphism $cl\colon \operatorname{Emb}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ sending an embedding to the class of hyperplane sections of $X$ in the embedding modulo linear equivalence.

Question: If the embeddings are chosen suitably, can any divisor of $X$ be written as the difference of two hyperplane sections?

In other words, is $cl$ surjective?

Comment: Every divisor can be expressed as the difference of two hyperplane sections for two different embeddings. Is that your question?

Comment: @Mohan Yes, that's my question.

Comment: I repeat, it is true. Let $D$ be any divisor and let $H$ be any hyperplane divisor for some embedding. Then, $D+nH$ is a hyperplane for all large $n$ and thus $D=(D+nH)-nH$. Both $D+nH, nH$ are hyperplanes for (different) embeddings.

Comment: Why is $D+nH$ a hyperplane for all large $n$? What precisely do you mean by large $n$?

Comment: Any divisor whose degree is larger than $2g+2$ is very ample and thus a hyperplane section for a suitable embedding, where $g$ is the genus.

Comment: @Mohan Of course, thanks.